# Paging in a ListBox (Panaroma Control)

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm using the default Panorama project in Windows Phone 7.1 and want to implement some kind of paging on the the first page's mvvm ListBox items. The sample project has 16 items, but I only want to show 4 at a time (and then buttons below showing next / previous). All of this in XAML.

I've looked around quite a bit and haven't discovered a way to make this happen. Does anyone know how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by your question the answer shouldn't *have* to be WP7 specific. Having said that you could pretty much get a listbox control with paging done in silverlight and add it inside of your Panorama page.

I did find this [page](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/Silverlight2PagedListBox.aspx?display=PrintAll) which shows how to do paging in silverlight with the listbox control and two buttons like you mentioned. Sorry, it's in VB but it shouldn't be difficult to transfer the logic to C#.

But like I said it's not really phone dependent to add paging because it's all xaml. So you could probably search "Paging Listbox in Silverlight" and should find something.

Comment: this is a good start, more than i found on my own. i'll check it out.